# How to perform group by in SQL Server for specific output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with few records, I want to get month wise data along with count on one of the column. The output should contain Month and count of Isregistered flag.

Table structure

```
| Inserted On | IsRegistered |
+-------------+--------------+
| 10-01-2020  | 1            |
| 15-01-2020  | 1            |
| 17-01-2020  | null         |
| 17-02-2020  | 1            |
| 21-02-2020  | null         |   
| 04-04-2020  | null         |
| 18-04-2020  | null         |
| 19-04-2020  | 1            |
```

Excepted output

```
| Inserted On | Registered | Not Registered
+-------------+------------+---------------
| Jan         |     2      |    1
| Feb         |     1      |    1
| Apr         |     1      |    2
```

I tried by performing normal group by but didn't got desired output

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(MONTH, dateinserted) AS [MonthName], COUNT(ISRegistered)
FROM
    tablename 
GROUP BY
    (DATENAME(MONTH, dateinserted))
```

Note: here null is treated as not registered

Comment: You say it didn't give the desired output; what was wrong with it? Your expected results  have 3 columns, but you only define 2 in your attempt. What happened to `NotRegistered`?

Comment: You chose non functioning code.  At least fix it so it works for the next person

Comment: @SteveC Gordon Linoff has already provided the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  I would include the year and use the month *number* rather than name, so:

```
select year(inserted_on), month(inserted_on),
       coalesce(sum(is_registered), 0) as num_registered,
       sum(case when is_registered is null then 1 else 0 end) as num_not_registered
from tablename
group by year(inserted_on), month(inserted_on)
order by year(inserted_on), month(inserted_on);
```

Note:  If you really want the monthname and want to combine data from different years (which seems unlikely, but . . . ), then you can use:

```
select datename(month, inserted_on),
       coalesce(sum(is_registered), 0) as num_registered,
       sum(case when is_registered is null then 1 else 0 end) as num_not_registered
from tablename
group by datename(month, inserted_on)
order by month(min(inserted_on));
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  tried the above query but got an error -Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator. do I need to cast as int ?

Comment: @VishalDhasal . . . Yes, you need to `cast()` to an `int`.

Comment: @Larnu . . . It is only extracting the month for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY should include both the year and month (so there's no overlapping) as well as the DATENAME (for display).  Something like this

```
drop table if exists #tablename;
go
create table #tablename(dateinserted date, ISRegistered int);
insert #tablename values 
('2020-12-01', 0),
('2020-11-02', 1),
('2020-11-03', 1),
('2020-12-01', 1),
('2020-12-03', 1),
('2020-11-02', 0);

select year(dateinserted) yr,
       datename(month, dateinserted) AS [MonthName], 
       sum(ISRegistered) Registered ,
       sum(1-ISRegistered) [Not Registered]
from #tablename 
group by year(dateinserted), month(dateinserted), datename(month, dateinserted)
order by year(dateinserted), month(dateinserted);
```

```
yr      MonthName   Registered  Not Registered
2020    November    2           1
2020    December    2           1
```